# Is there a way to save an UMA avatar recipe **including its escape characters** to my database?

Tags: php, mysql, unity-game-engine

In unity I have an UMA character creator.

At the end it gives me an avatar recipe that will let me load the saved character.

I want to save this avatar recipe to my mysql database.

So I pass the recipe to a stored proc on the server and try to save it but it wont load because the escape characters have been removed.

Here is an example:

this is an UMA recipe that WORKS:

```
{"packedRecipeType":"DynamicCharacterAvatar","name":"Player","race":"HumanMaleDCS","dna":[{"dnaType":"DynamicUMADna","dnaTypeHash":815443803,"packedDna":"{\"bDnaAsset\":{\"instanceID\":26992},\"bDnaAssetName\":\"HumanMaleDynamicDnaAsset\",\"bDnaSettings\":[{\"name\":\"skinGreenness\",\"value\":128}, etc... it goes on like that for a long time
```

BUT in my db it looks like this:

```
{"packedRecipeType":"DynamicCharacterAvatar","name":"Player","race":"HumanMaleDCS","dna":[{"dnaType":"DynamicUMADna","dnaTypeHash":815443803,"packedDna":"{"bDnaAsset":{"instanceID":26992},"bDnaAssetName":"HumanMaleDynamicDnaAsset","bDnaSettings":[{"name":"skinGreenness","value":128}, etc..
```

Here is the critical difference
`\"bDnaAssetName\"` becomes `"bDnaAssetName"`
and
`\"HumanMaleDynamicDnaAsset\"` becomes `"HumanMaleDynamicDnaAsset"`
etc...

The \ (s) disappeared!!!

So:

1. can I save this string with all of its backslashes so it works when I go to reload it?
2. is that even a good idea? am I opening myself up for trouble? is there a better way to save an UMA recipe to my db?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I eventually got this to work by using PHP `addslashes()`

Here is the PHP fecthing the POST

```
$Recipe = addslashes($_POST["Recipe"]);

//Query DB
$qry = "UPDATE player SET AvatarRecipe = '$Recipe' WHERE ID = '$PlayerID' ";
```

Now it saves to the Database in a form that UMA can read it when I go to load the avatar.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with saving recipes as json fields in postgresql. The problem comes from the UMA devs wrapping a json in a json. It's essentially a nested json string which causes nothing but problems. I told them about it months ago, and posted some code to help, but I don't think they ever updated it.

In any case, my code will assess the root of the problem by converting the outer json of the recipe into generics, and leaving the inner one alone. It's still a bit of a hack, since I had to nest the json again in order to load a recipe. Here is the code, which you can drop anywhere in your asset folder:

```
// Brought to you by Tarball 5/28/2019
// Drop in Asset folder to save your UMA data to generic types
// Call public methods from any script

using UMA.CharacterSystem;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace UMA
{
    namespace EasyMode
    {
        public static class EasyUMA
        {
            public static List<UMAPackedRecipeBase.UMAPackedDna> dnaPackedRecipe = new List<UMAPackedRecipeBase.UMAPackedDna>();
            public static UMAPackedRecipeBase.UMAPackedDna packedDna = new UMAPackedRecipeBase.UMAPackedDna();
            public static Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, string>> DNAInfo = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, string>>();
            public static Dictionary<string, short[]> colorRecipe = new Dictionary<string, short[]>();
            public static Dictionary<string, string> wardrobeRecipe = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            public static UMATextRecipe.DCSPackRecipe totalRecipe = new UMATextRecipe.DCSPackRecipe();
            public static bool saveAsMale;
            public static string[] colorNames;
            public static short[][] colorData;

            private static DynamicCharacterAvatar.SaveOptions saveOptions = DynamicCharacterAvatar.SaveOptions.saveDNA
                    | DynamicCharacterAvatar.SaveOptions.saveColors | DynamicCharacterAvatar.SaveOptions.saveWardrobe;

            private static Dictionary<string, string> wardrobe_slots = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            private static Dictionary<string, short[]> UMA_colors = new Dictionary<string, short[]>();
            private static List<UMAPackedRecipeBase.UMAPackedDna> dnaList = new List<UMAPackedRecipeBase.UMAPackedDna>();

            // Returns the current DCSPackRecipe from a DynamicCharacterAvatar
            private static UMATextRecipe.DCSPackRecipe packedRecipe(DynamicCharacterAvatar currentAvatar)
            {
                if (currentAvatar != null)
                {
                    return new UMATextRecipe.DCSPackRecipe(currentAvatar, currentAvatar.name, "DynamicCharacterAvatar", saveOptions);
                }
                else return null;
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Returns a Dictionary with raw DNA information for saving in c# generic types
            /// </summary>
            public static Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, string>> PrintDNADictionary(DynamicCharacterAvatar dynamicCharacterAvatar)
            {
                if (dynamicCharacterAvatar != null)
                {
                    dnaList = packedRecipe(dynamicCharacterAvatar).dna;
                    if (dnaList != null && dnaList.Count != 0)
                    {
                        Dictionary<string, string> tempStrings = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                        Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, string>> tempDict = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, string>>();
                        tempStrings.Add(dnaList.First().dnaType, dnaList.First().packedDna);
                        tempDict.Add(dnaList.First().dnaTypeHash, tempStrings);
                        return tempDict;
                    }
                    else return null;
                }
                else return null;
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Returns a Dictionary with wardrobe information in the format: (string wardrobe_slot_name, string wardrobe_item_name), for example ("Chest", "BreastPlate001")
            /// </summary>
            public static Dictionary<string, string> PrintWardrobe(DynamicCharacterAvatar dynamicCharacterAvatar)
            {
                if (dynamicCharacterAvatar != null)
                {
                    var recipe = packedRecipe(dynamicCharacterAvatar);
                    wardrobe_slots.Clear();
                    foreach (WardrobeSettings wardrobe_item in recipe.wardrobeSet)
                    {
                        wardrobe_slots.Add(wardrobe_item.slot, wardrobe_item.recipe);
                    }
                    return wardrobe_slots;
                }
                else return null;
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Returns a Dictionary with shared color information (string color_name, short[] RGBA_numbers)
            /// </summary>
            public static Dictionary<string, short[]> PrintColors(DynamicCharacterAvatar dynamicCharacterAvatar)
            {
                if (dynamicCharacterAvatar != null)
                {
                    var recipe = packedRecipe(dynamicCharacterAvatar);
                    colorNames = new string[recipe.characterColors.Count];
                    colorData = new short[recipe.characterColors.Count][];
                    int i = 0;
                    UMA_colors.Clear();
                    foreach (UMAPackedRecipeBase.PackedOverlayColorDataV3 charColors in recipe.characterColors)
                    {
                        UMA_colors.Add(charColors.name, charColors.colors);
                        colorNames[i] = charColors.name;
                        colorData[i] = charColors.colors;
                        i++;
                    }
                    return UMA_colors;
                }
                else return null;
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Returns the full recipe as a DCSPackRecipe 
            /// </summary>
            public static UMATextRecipe.DCSPackRecipe gatherFullRecipe(DynamicCharacterAvatar currentAvatar, bool isMale,
                Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, string>> DNAInfo, Dictionary<string, short[]> colorsData, Dictionary<string, string> wardrobeData)
            {
                UMATextRecipe.DCSPackRecipe recipe = new UMATextRecipe.DCSPackRecipe();
                UMAPackedRecipeBase.UMAPackedDna item = new UMAPackedRecipeBase.UMAPackedDna();
                if (DNAInfo != null && DNAInfo.Count != 0)
                {
                    item.dnaTypeHash = DNAInfo.First().Key;
                    item.dnaType = DNAInfo.First().Value.First().Key;
                    item.packedDna = DNAInfo.First().Value.First().Value;
                    List<UMAPackedRecipeBase.UMAPackedDna> senselessList = new List<UMAPackedRecipeBase.UMAPackedDna>();
                    senselessList.Add(item);
                    recipe.dna = senselessList;
                }

                if (isMale)
                    recipe.race = "HumanMale";
                else recipe.race = "HumanFemale";

                if (colorsData != null && colorsData.Count != 0)
                {
                    UMAPackedRecipeBase.PackedOverlayColorDataV3[] overlays = new UMAPackedRecipeBase.PackedOverlayColorDataV3[colorsData.Count];
                    recipe.characterColors = new List<UMAPackedRecipeBase.PackedOverlayColorDataV3>();
                    int i = 0;
                    foreach (var uniqueColor in colorsData)
                    {
                        overlays[i] = new UMAPackedRecipeBase.PackedOverlayColorDataV3();
                        overlays[i].name = uniqueColor.Key;
                        overlays[i].colors = uniqueColor.Value;
                        recipe.characterColors.Add(overlays[i]);
                        i++;
                    }
                }

                if (wardrobeData != null && wardrobeData.Count != 0)
                {
                    WardrobeSettings[] wardrobeInfo = new WardrobeSettings[wardrobeData.Count];
                    recipe.wardrobeSet = new List<WardrobeSettings>();
                    int i = 0;
                    foreach (var wardrobePiece in wardrobeData)
                    {
                        wardrobeInfo[i] = new WardrobeSettings();
                        wardrobeInfo[i].slot = wardrobePiece.Key;
                        wardrobeInfo[i].recipe = wardrobePiece.Value;
                        recipe.wardrobeSet.Add(wardrobeInfo[i]);
                        i++;
                    }
                }
                return recipe;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, you should be able to save in any database, without too much trouble. The recipe is split into a few pieces, now, however. To save/load, simply put this code snippet in your script which handles saving and loading:

```
private DynamicCharacterAvatar avatar;

public void SaveRecipe()
    {
        EasyUMA.DNAInfo = EasyUMA.PrintDNADictionary(avatar);
        EasyUMA.colorRecipe = EasyUMA.PrintColors(avatar);

        EasyUMA.wardrobeRecipe = EasyUMA.PrintWardrobe(avatar);

        if (avatar.umaData.umaRecipe.raceData.raceName == "HumanMale")
            EasyUMA.saveAsMale = true;
        else EasyUMA.saveAsMale = false;
    }

    public void LoadRecipe()
    {
        avatar.ClearSlots();
        EasyUMA.dnaPackedRecipe.Clear();
        EasyUMA.dnaPackedRecipe.Add(EasyUMA.packedDna);
        EasyUMA.totalRecipe = EasyUMA.gatherFullRecipe(avatar, EasyUMA.saveAsMale, EasyUMA.DNAInfo, EasyUMA.colorRecipe, EasyUMA.wardrobeRecipe);
        var dummyRecipe = JsonUtility.ToJson(EasyUMA.totalRecipe);
        avatar.LoadFromRecipeString(dummyRecipe);
    }
```